# Accessing an Attribute in a different Controller Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext

I have an field is a Controller Class(User) that keeps track of the current User. In a different Controller Class (Blog) I want to access that attribute(CurrentUser) but the issue is that I have to create a new instance of the controller class which doesn't work. Is there a good way to access this attribute without creating a new class?

Here is an example:

User Controller Class:

```
public class UserController : Controller 
{
    public int CurrentUserId = -1; // This line as been removed

    //Methods go below
    // ...

    public void Login(User user)
    {
           HttpContext.Items["UserId"] = user.Id;
    }
```

Blog Controller Class:

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NewBlogPost(Article ArticleToCreate)
    {
         ArticleToCreate.AudthorId = (int)HttpContext.Items["UserId"];
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using attributes to store data? (I don't see any attributes in your snippets...) Are you using static wrapper properties or something? It seems like the wrong way to go about things, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: How would you go about saving the current user?

Comment: Your title mentions attributes but there are none in your code sample. Something isn't right here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, I don't think that you really mean to Attribute, but to Field.

This is how a Attribute looks like:

```
[HelpAttribute("http://localhost/MyClassInfo")]
```

And this is how a Field looks like:

```
public int CurrentUserId = -1;
```

**Second**, if all you need is the user details, use the `User` property: `HttpContext.Current.User` in your `Action` context.

You can use it in any `Controller`, since `HttpContext` is a `Controller` property (`this.HttpContext`).

As for sharing other controllers data, I don't think that it make any sense because each new request initialize another `Controller` class instance, HTTP is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

In addition, in order to add extra user's details, like: `UserId`, use the `HttpContext.Items` `Dictionary` property,
This data will be available for you in any controller, at any new request, just like the `User` property, for example:

```
HttpContext.Items["UserId"] = 200;
```

**UPDATE**

In order to be able to access the `HttpContext.Items` property at any Conroller's Action, set it in the `Application_BeginRequest` handler in the `Global.asax` file and not in the `Controller`, as you did:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
  int userId = //Logic to retrieve the `UserId`.
  Context.Items["UserId"] = userId;
}
```

This is an ideal spot to load request specific state to carry through until ASP.NET MVC completes the request.

Comment: How woulg i set this property to a value?

Comment: @user977154 Basically, if you are working with one of the authentication mechanisms, the User details should be there for you.

Comment: it says Current does not exist

Comment: Okay so I was debugging my code. I set the property when a user logs in and I see the value being saved to the property. But then when I try to get the property in the other controller it comes up with a null result

Comment: Okay, but I cannot get the userId because it is being generated in the  UserController class under the login method

Comment: I really appreciate your help by the way

Comment: @user977154 Move this logic to the `Application_BeginRequest`. You can  access Form values, like this: `Request.Form["UserID"]`